# Applying 9-patch png on android

Tags: android, button, nine-patch, android-drawable

I'm using 9-patch images to create selector for buttons that can be stretched in different screen size. So I basically pass the name of the files (without the .9.png) in the selector like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/img_common_white_button_bg_pressed" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/img_common_white_button_bg_default" />

</selector>
```

And I thought this should be okay. The graphical layout screen of the xml doesn't show any problem with the button, but when I run the app in my device, this is what I get:

[image]

So I'm not sure whether I applied the images the wrong way or is it the problem of the 9-patch files? I'll really appreciate it if someone could enlighten me with this. Thank you.

Comment: your file name should be like this img_name.9.png. Use this to draw p patch http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html

Comment: my files are img_name.9.png, then do i have to state it in the xml like this `android:drawable="@drawable/img_name.9"`?

Comment: No need to do like this simply give `android:drawable="@drawable/img_name"`. At starting itself your have applied correct so problem is not in way of  apply but  problem may be in your image.

Comment: @friedegg-bacon-sandwich I have created 9 patch images from Android Asset Tool http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html but generated images gives `Failed to parse file drawable/btnpressed.xml` and `Failed to parse file drawable/btn.xml` in graphical layout screen.You have any idea about this problem.

Comment: @ved seems like that's a different issue you're having. Make sure you entered the right file name and clean the project. There are many questions on this site about that issue.

Comment: @friedegg-bacon-sandwich I am using right file name and it is properly render on device when I run the app but on graphical layout screen it shows this error in Error log. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider below mentioned things about  9-patch image:

**->**.9.png image has black border around the image that indicate it's patch.

**->** in drawable folder image having .9.png are identified as 9-patch image so it's must that 9 patch image have .9.png as extension

In your case you removed .9 from image name so it will be normal drawable having black border around image.

you have 2 option. remove patch from button recreate it for all android drawable size.
OR remain 9 patch image with it's extention .9.png in drawable folder.

Comment: Yes my files are 9-patch images, they were generated with android asset tool and has the .9.png naming convention. My question is, do I have to pass the full name (with the postfix) to the xml file for it to work? Because currently I'm using them like above and they show the edges

Comment: No need to define postfix in selector file it can be implemented as normal images.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I did and the edges show. Does that mean there's something wrong with the 9-patch images?

Comment: your button is not square . it has curly corners. that's why it may be image patches are wrong . regenerate 9 patch image for button and try.

Comment: @friedegg-bacon-sandwich, how you solved your problem ?? i have the same issue

Comment: @umesh my problem was caused due to the corrupted image patches. You may want to re-generate your images using android asset tool: http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html

Answer (score 1):

pls check if you copy the .9.png into all resolution folders  e.g. drawable-hdpi drawable-xhpdi drawable-xxhdpi.

it sounds like Android would stretch even border area(static area) if running device dpi is not the same as it should be with resolution folder e.g. if you only copy .9.png into drawable folder, the border would be stretched as 3 times wide if running  on a device with dpi as 3.

Answer (score 0):

Rename your image as 
img_common_white_button_bg_default.9.png

and

img_common_white_button_bg_pressed.9.png .

**Note:** A normal PNG file (*.png) will be loaded with an empty one-pixel border added around the image, in which you can draw the stretchable patches and content area. A previously saved 9-patch file (*.9.png) will be loaded as-is, with no drawing area added, because it already exists.

Read official doc: [Draw 9-patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)